# Sencha Touch - List/nestesList with images

Tags: image, sencha-touch, extjs, nested-lists

I've started working with Sencha Touch this morning and I could use some help.

If I create a nestedList like this:

```
var data = {
    text: 'Groceries',
    items: [{
        text: 'Ninja',
        items: [{
            text: 'Water',
            items: [{
                text: 'Sparkling',
                leaf: true
            },{
                text: 'Still',
                leaf: true
            }]
        },{
            text: 'Coffee',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Espresso',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Redbull',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Coke',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Diet Coke',
            leaf: true
        }]
    }],{
        text: 'Fruit',
        items: [{
            text: 'Bananas',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Lemon',
            leaf: true
        }]
    },{
        text: 'Snacks',
        items: [{
            text: 'Nuts',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Pretzels',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Wasabi Peas',
            leaf: true
        }]
    },{
        text: 'Empty Category',
        items: []
    }]
};
```

How can I add images to the list? For example if I wanted to have the Coca Cola Logo next to the string diet coke. I tried setting html whith an image inside but that just gave me a blank item. I can't find anything on how to manipulate list items despite the "text" property. I know it's possible though because I saw an example containing a contact list with contact photos.

I hope you can help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post a current working example of what you have so far

Answer (score 7):

You can add extra fields to your `Ext.regModel`, so you want to add one to hold the path to you image.

You can add any HTML you want to the lists `itemTpl` so you can add your image in there.

The example below is from the [sencha api docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/), I modified it to use images to give you an idea of how you can add them.

Hope that helps!

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.setup({
    icon: 'icon.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    onReady: function() {

        Ext.regModel('Contact', {
            fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'imgURL']
        });

        var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            model: 'Contact',
            sorters: 'lastName',

            getGroupString: function(record) {
                return record.get('lastName')[0];
            },

            data: [{
                firstName: 'Tommy',
                lastName: 'Maintz',
                imgURL: 'myImage.png'
            }, {
                firstName: 'Rob',
                lastName: 'Dougan',
                imgURL: 'myImage.png'
            }, {
                firstName: 'Ed',
                lastName: 'Spencer',
                imgURL: 'myImage.pngg'
            }, {
                firstName: 'Jamie',
                lastName: 'Avins',
                imgURL: 'myImage.png'
            }]
        });

        var list = new Ext.List({
            fullscreen: true,

            itemTpl: '<img src="{imgURL}" width="20" heigh="20"></img><span>{firstName} {lastName}</span>',
            //grouped : true,
            //indexBar: true,

            store: store
        });
        list.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer.. But..Why cant the same be achieved on nestedlist??? Do u know how to add images and also other html components to nested List items??? pls help!!!